# Why do I have to hide back button item before implementing custom left barButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

Here's my code for removing the back UIBarButtonItem of a navigation bar and replacing it with a cancel button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButtonItem;
```

Every example I've seen online doesn't hide the backButton before replacing it with a custom item. I may be wrong but it just seems like one unneeded line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel` instead of `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` in the style of your `UIBarButtonItem`?

Try this,

```
    UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Also if you have used `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in your `parentViewController`,  it will show that button in the childViewController's leftBarButtonItem by default, if your custom leftBarButton in the childViewController is not added properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Write this in your app delegates  did finish launching.

```
LoginViewController *loginVc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVc];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;

// and use uibutton in your view controller at place of back button or cancel button
// and u can push or pop your view from there.
```